# AngularJs DELETE with data sets wrong content-type header

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

I am making a $http DELETE request with a payload but the content-type is wrong.  I have a data object, but the content-type is getting set to text/plain instead of application/json.  As you can see from the code below and the network request below there is in fact a data object with values.  Is there a work around for this?  Much Thanks!

code:

```
    $http({  
        method: "DELETE",  
        url: ".../v2/places/" + place.id + "/locations/remove",  
        data: location,  
        headers: { Authorization: "Bearer " + rootServices.getToken() }  
    })
```

chrome network request summary:

> Remote Address:54.83.54.37:443
>   URL:../v2/places/53b43e03e4b00cb25bcb16af/locations/remove
>   Request Method:DELETE
>     Status Code:500 Internal Server Error Request
>   Accept:application/json, text/plain, `*/*`
>   Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
>   Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
>   Authorization:Bearer .....
>     Connection:keep-alive
>   Content-Length:66
>   Content-Type:text/plain;charset=UTF-8
>   Host:sandbox....net
>   Origin:127.0.0.1:9000
>   Referer:127.0.0.1:9000/session
>   User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36
>   (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36 Request
>   Payload:  {room:Kitchen, appliance:Refrigerator, floor:Main
>   Floor}

Comment: I see a `content-type` header.

Comment: It is getting set to text/plain instead of application/json.  I assumed that was the default if there was no content-type specified.

Comment: Your question is about the content type being stripped which is kind of contradictory when you post the content-type that is being sent.  Consequently as you are passing in some of your own headers, you can set it to whatever you want or do it in your app's config.  See docs  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can set the content type in the headers along with the Authorization header

```
$http({  
        method: "DELETE",  
        url: ".../v2/places/" + place.id + "/locations/remove",  
        data: location,  
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json', Authorization: "Bearer " + rootServices.getToken() }  
    })
```

Or you can set them app wide:

```
module.config(function($httpProvider) {
  //$http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = 'Basic YmVlcDpib29w'
  $httpProvider.defaults.headers.delete = { 'Content-Type' : 'application/json' };
});
```

The docs state:

> Setting HTTP Headers The $http service will automatically add certain
>   HTTP headers to all requests. These defaults can be fully configured
>   by accessing the $httpProvider.defaults.headers configuration object,
>   which currently contains this default configuration:
>
> $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common (headers that are common for all
>   requests): Accept: application/json, text/plain, * / *
>   $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post: (header defaults for POST
>   requests) Content-Type: application/json
>   $httpProvider.defaults.headers.put (header defaults for PUT requests)
>   Content-Type: application/json To add or overwrite these defaults,
>   simply add or remove a property from these configuration objects. To
>   add headers for an HTTP method other than POST or PUT, simply add a
>   new object with the lowercased HTTP method name as the key, e.g.
>   `$httpProvider.defaults.headers.get = { 'My-Header' : 'value' }.
>
> The defaults can also be set at runtime via the $http.defaults object
>   in the same fashion. For example:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: Thank You.  I feel pretty stupid assuming $httpProvider defaulted content-type to application/json

Answer (score 2):

I found out the problem.
We need to type "content-type" instead of "Content-Type".
If i understand it, the lower case override the previous.

I will show an example:

```
$scope.deleteObject = function (object) {
    var objectId = object.id;
    var url = '/services/rest/deleteObject/' + objectId;
    var config = {
        headers: {
            'content-type': 'application/json'
        }
    };
    $http.delete(url, config)

    .then(function (response) {
        DO SOMETHING

    }, function (error) {
        DO SOMETHING
    });

};
```